# Does Odion's "Chain Reaction" Skill count as Effect Damage?

Tags: yu-gi-oh-duel-links

Odion has the "Chain Reaction" skill that has the following description:

> Inflict 200 points of damage to your opponent's Life every time you activate a Trap Card.

Is this considered Effect Damage? Can I use it to help complete the missions that require dealing X amount of Effect Damage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

It does not count as card effect damage. I tried to do the 4000 effect damage in one duel using this skill and the task was not accepted.
After switching the skill, it was okay.

[This Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/DuelLinks/comments/5su3rp/heads_up_on_odions_skill_in_relation_to_missions/) mentions the issue as well.